# Rx.Net : perform asynchronous side-effect when subscription is disposed

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a device that communicates with the computer via the serial port. Upon sending a "START" command, the device responds with an acknowledgement and it starts monitoring some external activity. It then asynchonousely transmitts some messages on the serial port depending on that external activity. When the device receives a "STOP" command, it responds with an acknowledgement, and then it stops sending more messages (representing the external activity).

I've implemented the Start/Stop commands with cold observables, that perform side-effects (send command on the serial port), and emits a single `Unit.Default` if an ackowledge is received on the SerialPort. I want to construct an `IObservable` that emits messages coresponding to the external activity, and perform "START" side-effect when it is subscribed to, and "STOP" side-effect when the subscription is disposed.
"START" is easy, i just have to do a `SelectMany', but i dont know how to perform "STOP".

```
  class MonitoringDevice
{
    private SerialPort _sp;
    private IObservable<byte> _receivedBytes;

    public IObservable<ExternalActivity> ActivityStream { get; }

    public  MonitoringDevice()
    {
        _sp = new SerialPort("COM1");
        _receivedBytes = Observable
                         .FromEventPattern<SerialDataReceivedEventHandler, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs>(
                          h =>
                          {
                              _sp.DiscardInBuffer();
                              _sp.DataReceived += h;
                          },
                          h =>
                          {
                              _sp.DataReceived -= h;
                          })
                         .SelectMany(x =>
                         {

                             byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                             var ret = new List<byte>();
                             int bytesRead = 0;
                             do
                             {
                                 bytesRead = _sp.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                 ret.AddRange(buffer.Take(bytesRead));
                             } while ((bytesRead >= buffer.Length));
                             return ret;

                         })
                         .Publish()
                         .RefCount();


        ActivityStream = StartMonitoringAsync()
                         .SelectMany( _receivedBytes.ToActivity());
                         // we need to execute StopMonitoringAsync 
                         // when a subscription to ActivityStream is disposed

        _sp.Open();
    }



    private IObservable<Unit> StartMonitoringAsync()
    {
        return Observable
               .Create<Unit>(
                obs =>
                {
                    _sp.Write("START");
                    return _receivedBytes
                           .ToAcknowledge()
                           .FirstAsync()
                           .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
                           .Subscribe(obs);
                });
    }


    private IObservable<Unit> StopMonitoringAsync()
    {
        return Observable
               .Create<Unit>(
                obs =>
                {
                    _sp.Write("STOP");
                    return _receivedBytes
                           .ToAcknowledge()
                           .FirstAsync()
                           .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
                           .Subscribe(obs);
                });
    }


}
```

`ExternalActivity` is just a POCO.

`ToAcknowledge` is an extension method returning an `IObservable` that emits `Unit.Default` when the device transmitts an acknowledgement. - this is working as expected;

`ToActivity` is an extension method returning an `IObservable` that parses the incomming serial data and emits `ExternalActivity` objects. - this is working as expected;

---

Edit : Added implementation for `ToAcknowledge` and `ToActivity` extension methods.

```
public static IObservable<Unit> ToAcknowledge(this IObservable<byte> source)
    {
        return source.Buffer(3, 1)
               .Where(bfr => bfr.SequenceEqual(new byte[] { 65, 67, 75 })) // ACK
               .Select(x => Unit.Default);

    }

    public static IObservable<ExternalActivity> ToActivity(this IObservable<byte> source)
    {
        return source
               .Publish(ps => ps.Buffer(ps.Where(x => x == 1),             // SOH
                                           bo => ps.Where(x => x == 4)))   // EOT
               .Select(bfr => bfr.Take(bfr.Count - 1).Skip(1))
               .Where(bfr => bfr.Count() == 12)
               .Select(bfr =>
               {
                   var timestamp = BitConverter.ToInt64(bfr.Take(8).ToArray(), 0);
                   var id = BitConverter.ToInt32(bfr.ToArray(), 8);
                   return new ExternalActivity(timestamp, id);
               });           
    }
```

Comment: Could you please show the code for `ToAcknowledge` & `ToActivity`? I can't give you an answer without them.

Comment: @Enigmativity - See my edited question.

Comment: Hmm I dont think in this case STOP and Dispose should be conflated to the same thing. I think you want to model Stop as a command. And as such accept that it can succeed, fail, timeout etc. Disposal is then just purely, disconnecting and trashing the subscription.

Comment: @LeeCampbell - That's a very good observation. There will be Start and Stop buttons on te UI side, so is logical to have those trigger some commands and react on success, fail, etc,  as you pointed out. There's actually no need to trigger those commands when subscribing/disposing to/from 'ActivityStream'. I wasn't seeing the big picture. If you could post your comment as an answer i will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `StartAsync` to be this:

```
private IObservable<Unit> StartAsync(Action unsubscribe)
{
    return
        Observable
            .Create<Unit>(o =>
            {
                var subscription =
                    Observable
                        .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                        .Select(_=> Unit.Default)
                        .Subscribe(o);
                return new CompositeDisposable(
                    subscription,
                    Disposable.Create(unsubscribe));
            });;
}
```

Then you can inject in any `Action unsubscribe` you like.

Try testing with this code:

```
var subscription =
    StartAsync(() => Console.WriteLine("Done"))
    .Subscribe();

Thread.Sleep(3000);

subscription.Dispose();
```

You'll see "Done" written to the console after 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks. The action to be performed on subscription disposal is an asynchronous one. It is implemented as a cold observable that performs side-effect (send command through SerialPort) and emits single value on response arrival. In my code example it's emulated with an `Observable.Timer`. I need to await this observable inside main subscription disposal.

Comment: @francezu13k50 - Could you not put an observable within the `Action`? However, it's never a good idea to rely on a timer to allow an asynchronous action to complete. Rx is very good at handling these situations properly. Can you show your real code?

Comment: I dont know how to put an observable within the `Action`. The `Observable.Timer` is there only to simulate the asynchronous response of the device, in effect to a "STOP" command; i'm not relying on a timer for action completeness, it's actually the device acknowledge that indicates the operation success.

Comment: @francezu13k50 - Then you should write your code to respond to the acknowledgement. Can you show your real code?

Comment: I've edited my question and added a more detailed code example. I hope that clarifies my situation.